# В чем опасность при обработки данных в двоичном коде?

Tags: php, безопасность

В мануалах вижу подобную информацию "С версии PHP 5.х функция безопасна для обработки данных в двоичной форме."
О какой опасности идет речь?

Comment: А какие это функции ?

Comment: @mike, например http://www.php.su/strip_tags()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это кривой перевод.
Никакой "опасности" тут нет.
Binary-safe всего лишь означает, что функция подходит для обработки бинарных данных. 
Т.е. строка может содержать любые символы, а не только текстовые.
Единственное практическое применение этого принципа - наличие в строке нулл байта:

- binary-safe функция прочтет строку целиком
- в противном случае чтение закончится на символе null.